# Как вывести сообщение из php в html?

Tags: php, html, forms

Написал простую форму:

```
<form action="email.php" method="post" name="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="sender" name="name" required><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="5" id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
    </div>
</form>
```

И php скрипт:

```
<?php
    mail('myMail@mail.com', $_POST['name'], $_POST['message']);
    print "Thank you for you comment!";
?>
```

Про нажатию кнопки на форме перекидывает на php страницу. Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку это же сообщение появлялось под формой? *(то есть сообщение "Thank you for you comment!" должно появляться на той же странице, где и форма, просто под ней)*

Comment: Javascript вам в помошь поссылке примеры с jquery и без.http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#json

Comment: И никто не предложил идеологически верный вариант с шаблонизатором :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого вы можете использовать JavaScript(jQuery) AJAX.

Подключите [jQuery](https://jquery.com), а после можете применить этот код

```
<form id="mail_form" method="post" name="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="sender" name="name" required><br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Message" rows="5" id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
        <button type="button" onclick="regAjax()">Send</button>
        <span id="result"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

И соответственно сама функция

```
function regAjax() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: jQuery("#mail_form").serialize(),
        url: 'email.php',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#result").text(data);
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Всё работает!

Comment: "необходимо" это перебор

Comment: @andreymal ))) поправил

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько вариантов.

1. И форму и сам скрипт реализовывать в одном файле и тогда вывод сообщения можно сделать где угодно.
2. Из скрипта email.php делать редирект обратно на форму, с каким-нибудь параметром GET и по наличию этого параметра выводить текст под формой или не выводить.
3. Добавить под формой iframe и выполнять скрипт в нем. Надо добавить в форму аттрибут target - указывающий на данный iframe
4. Использовать AJAX

Comment: Минус так как все 4 варианта кастыли.

Comment: @Naumov а что по вашему не костыль в данном случае?

Comment: Пишите в сессию сообщение и отображаете потом удаляете в bootstrap есть классы сообщений, 1. кастыль по тому что обновим страницу и будем получать сообщение отправить форму ещё раз. 2. кастыль т.к. таже история этот якорь придёться удалять.
3. ну iframe и так понятно
4. отключёный js теряем функционал

Comment: Ни какая функциональная часть не должна быть завязаной на js

Comment: Те кто ставит плюс может отпишитесь почему? приведите аргументы плюсы за 4 этих варианта?

Comment: @Naumov ну на счет 4го спорно. скажем прямо сейчас без js ходят только те, кто и так в курсе как там чего и зачем они его отключили, потому что уже пол веба без js работать не будет и у простого юзера эта ситуация просто нереальна. ну а первые три пхп-треш обычный, да)

Comment: @kroder Да может быть и так, но хорошее решение это которое работает в любой ситуации, и на большинстве браузеров, А иначе сначала сообщение на js поже расчёты на нём же и т.д. и т.п. От сюда и родилась фраза `у меня всё работает`.

Comment: *Ни какая функциональная часть не должна быть завязаной на js* - это вы в эпоху SPA и поголовного ангуляра такое заявляете? )

Comment: @Nofate Приведу несколько примеров из жизни, `цены в инет магазине считались на js` человек разрабатывающий это тоже оперался на эпоху. А вообще есть методология разработки 'прогрессивная разработка' т.е. когда пишеться html, после на него накладывают css, и после js... Да и мы не знаем точно какой комп у клиента.

Comment: @Naumov может вы напутали - там на `js` подсчитывалась цена чисто визуально, чтоб пользователь знал сколько чего осталось, а настоящий подсчет уже велся на сервере? Если  на `js` считалось и на сервер отправлялось, то это в принципе разработчик идиот, ибо это небезопасно.....а визуально показать юзеру - вполне себе нормально и адекватно и правильно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вы не поверите сколько таких :D это аргумент в силу `Ни какая функциональная часть не должна быть завязаной на js` и против высказывания Nofate. так как отправка формы это тоже часть функционала, и отправка её только на js это в корне неправильно. Да если мы хотим такцю свисто-перделку пожалуйста, но форма должна иметь и action и submit кнопку но если js включен то при клике на сабмит запускаем ajax и ставим чтобы форма не отправлялась, когда нет js всё работает так как и должно.

Comment: @Naumov так он вам про SPA и ангуляры, а вы ему про инет магазин......А параноиков......в смысле людей, не использующих js крайне мал, ими можно также пренебречь, как и теми, кто юзает IE5-6-7  и всякие хромы версии 2.0.3

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Безусловно мы можем ими пренебречь, что бы не думать и не тратить время :D но это же не правильно http://frontender.info/everyone-has-js/ наткнулся на диаграмму когда то читал это на английском